# Lagrange multipliers to optimize sum of cubes of roots of a quadratic

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

> If $\lambda \geq -2$ such that the sum of cubes of roots of the equation $x^2 + (2-\lambda )x + (10-\lambda) = 0$ is minimum, then the magnitude of difference of root is..?

Let roots be $\alpha $ and $\beta$, we wish to maximize $f(\alpha,\beta) = \alpha^3 + \beta^3$ under the constraint of $ \alpha + \beta = 2- \lambda $ and $\alpha \beta= 10 -\lambda$ , combining the constraints we get:

$$ \alpha + \beta + \alpha \beta = 8$$

Now apply lagrange multiplier equation, we get:

$$ 3 \alpha^2 = \mu ( 1 + \beta)$$

And,

$$ 3 \beta^2 = \mu ( 1 + \alpha)$$

Taking the ratio of the two equations:

$$ \frac{\alpha^2 }{\beta^2} = \frac{1+\beta}{1 + \alpha} \tag{1}$$

Substracting one on both sides:

$$ \frac{\alpha + \beta}{\beta^2} =  \frac{-1}{1+\alpha} \tag{2}$$

This leads to:

$$ \alpha + \beta + \alpha^2 + \alpha \beta  = - \beta^2$$

Hence,

$$ -12 = \alpha^2 + \beta^2$$

Now.. I am not sure what to do. One way is to ditch the lagrange multiplier approach and directly express the objective function in terms of $\lambda$ and minimize but is there a way to proceed further from the information we have?

Comment: Is the equation correct? You have written $\alpha + \beta = 2 - \lambda$ but it should be $\lambda - 2$ if the equation is correct.

Comment: @MathLover It is , the answer has some complex values

Comment: OK then $\alpha + \beta$ should be $\lambda - 2$ and $\alpha+\beta+\alpha\beta$ should be $8$.

Comment: Fixed that @MathLover

Comment: It is much easier to solve by expressing objective function in terms of $\lambda$ as you mentioned. Are $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Not neccesarily, they can be complex @MathLover

Comment: See that is the issue. If you see graph of $\alpha^3 + \beta^3 = \lambda^3 - 3 \lambda^2 - 24 \lambda + 52$, there is no global min. If they are real then there is a solution otherwise I do not think so. Critical points are $\lambda = -2, 4$.

Comment: They said magnitude like complex modulus , so it still makes sense ig @MathLover

Comment: Is the answer $\alpha - \beta =  2 \sqrt5 \ i$?

Comment: You should take modulus $|\alpha - \beta| $ so answer is 2 sqrt(5) @MathLover

Comment: Yes I know how they are getting that but that is not correct answer in my view. They are calculating at a local minima but they are missing the point that for $\lambda \leq -2$, the function is monotonically decreasing so $\alpha^3+\beta^3$ has no minimum.

Comment: OMG hahahahaha that is a good point. I didn't even think of that mistake in the question

Comment: Fixed the question @MathLover (I didn't create this, it was taken from JEE exam). The OG question was exact one, now I fixed it to so that it is logically sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution without Lagrange Multiplier method. See my edit in the end for Lagrange Multiplier method.

$\alpha + \beta = \lambda-2, \alpha\beta = 10 - \lambda$

$f(\alpha, \beta) = \alpha^3 + \beta^3 = (\alpha + \beta)^3 - 3 \alpha \beta(\alpha + \beta)$

So, $f(\alpha, \beta) = (\lambda-2)^3 - 3 (10-\lambda)(\lambda-2) = \lambda^3 - 3 \lambda^2 - 24 \lambda + 52$

Now we take derivative with respect to $\lambda$ and equate to $0$,

$\lambda^2 - 2\lambda-8 = 0 \implies \lambda = -2, 4$

Second derivative test confirms a local minima at $\lambda = 4$. We also observe that the function $f$ is monotonically decreasing for $\lambda \lt - 2$ and is monotonically increasing for $\lambda \gt 4$. So in the given domain $\lambda \geq - 2$, absolute minima occurs at $\lambda = 4$.

And so we have,
$\alpha + \beta = \lambda - 2 = 2, \alpha \beta = 10 - \lambda = 6$

Solving, $\alpha = 1 \pm i \sqrt 5, \beta = 1 \mp i \sqrt5$, which are complex roots of the quadratic for $\lambda = 4$.

---

For Lagrange Multiplier method,

Say $\alpha + \beta = x, \alpha \beta = y$

You found $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = - 8$. We also have $y = 8 - x$

$x^2 = - 8 + 2y = - 8 + 16 - 2x \implies x^2 + 2x - 8 = 0 \ $
(where $x = \alpha + \beta$)

Solving $x = 2, y = 6; x = - 4, y = 12$.

We test $\alpha^3 + \beta^3 = x^3 - 3 xy$ for both and obtain $x = 2, y = 6$ to be the minima.

$(\alpha-\beta)^2 = x^2 - 4y = - 20 \implies \alpha-\beta = \pm \sqrt{-20}$

Comment: This is a good idea but I had done it this way :P I was trying to figure out how to make lagrange work

Comment: I added details for Lagrange Multiplier method.

Comment: Great! I'm slightly upset that it ended up being algebra bashing but still thank you for your time and expertise!